# How to display none all ul,li tags inside a div except the li having an a tag with class html

Tags: jquery

I have a Div with contents

```
<div id="dv">

<ul><li><a class="html">abcd</a></li></ul>

<ul><li><a class="bold">cdef</a></li></ul>

<ul><li><a class="bold">xyz</a></li></ul>

</div>
```

I want to display none second and 3rd ul dynamically. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find all the children of the div, hide them, then find the `ul` containing the `li` with class `"html"` and show that `ul`:

```
$("#dv").children('ul').hide().find('li.html').closest('ul').show();
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/iyavuk/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/iyavuk/1/edit)

What that does:

- [`$("#dv")`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) - Finds the relevant div
- [`.children('ul')`](http://api.jquery.com/children) - Finds its children that are `ul` elements
- [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide) - Hides them
- [`.find('a.html')`](http://api.jquery.com/find) - Finds any `a` elements withinin those `ul`s that have class `"html"`
- [`.closest('ul')`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) - Gets the `ul` containing that `a` element
- [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show) - Shows it

Answer (score 1):

You can Use below `jQuery`

```
$("#dv ul:nth-child(2),#dv ul:nth-child(3)").hide()
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest I can think of is this

```
$("#dv li a:not(.html)").parent().hide();
```

EDIT:
@ByScripts suggested using `closest()` instead of `parent()`.

```
$("#dv li a:not(.html)").closest("ul").hide();
```

Comment: This is a good answer. I think it can even be shorter : `$('#dv a:not(.html)').closest('ul').hide()`. However I would use closest(à instead of parent().

Comment: yes, that'd be shorter.

Comment: @ByScripts I did not use `.closest()`, just in case if he decides to add something after that anchor, it wouldn't work as expected.

Comment: Yes, but `closest` looks for ascendants only. And he want to hide `<ul>`, not `<li>` Even if adding something after the anchor, `closest('ul')` should always get the parent `<ul>`

Comment: @ByScripts Oh dear, I did not notice that each of them were a different `<ul>`, my bad. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
$("#dv ul").hide(); // hide all divs
$("#dv a.html").closest("ul").show(); // show the div that contains a.html
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display none all ul except first ul then try this code:

```
$("#dv ul").css('display','none');
if($("#dv ul").hasClass('html')){
$(".html").closest('ul').('display','block');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use [slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) if the requirement is to hide the second and third `ul`.

```
$('#dv ul').slice(1).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

As far I understood you want to remove the `<li>` with  `a` class 'html' . Below is the code

```
$("#div ul li a.html").hide(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on xFortyFourx answer :

```
$("#dv a:not(.html)").closest('ul').hide();
```

**Edit :** I think a lot of participants didn't read the title. The OP wants to hide `<ul>` according to `class="html"` of `<a>` elements. `slice()` is not a solution ;)